# Malicious code vulnerability - Field should be package protected

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonar is giving me the message:

> Malicious code vulnerability - Field should be package protected for
>   static array `FORMATS`.

Why is this code considered malicious? I have a public class to store all the constants.

```
public class Constants
{
    /*
    all the public static final constants of primitive datatypes for which 
    there is no sonar warning.
    */
    public static final String[] FORMATS = new String[] {
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z", 
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Probably because another piece of code could execute:

```
Constants.FORMATS[0] = "SOME GARBAGE";
```

And break the rest of your code.

In other words your array is constant but not its content.

Examples of alternatives:

- you can store each format as a separate String constant
- you can use an immutable list instead: `public static final List<String> FORMATS = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"));`
- make it a method:

  ```
  public static String[] formats() {
    return new String[] { "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S" };
  }
  ```
- ignore the warning if you are confident that (i) only your own code will access that class and (ii) there is no way you/your colleagues would even think of reassigning one of the values.

Comment: so final would just prevent re-assign like FORMATS = new String[] {"a","b"}. But that's bad so I have to use a immutable list then?

Comment: Yes that's the problem and that's one possibility.